# Дана матрица. Нужно написать функцию, которая для элемента возвращает всех его соседей

Tags: python

Новичок, изучаю Python. Если вкратце, есть задача, дана матрица. Нужно написать функцию, которая для элемента возвращает всех его соседей. Соседним считается элемент, находящийся от текущего на одну ячейку влево, вправо, вверх или вниз. Диагональные элементы соседними не считаются.

Например, в матрице A:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[0, 2, 6],
[7, 4, 1],
[2, 7, 0]]
```

соседними элементами для (0, 0) будут 2 и 0 А для (2, 1) — 1, 2, 7, 7.

Формат ввода:
В первой строке задано n - количество строк матрицы. Во второй - m - количество столбцов. Числа m и n не превосходят 1000. В следующих n строках задана матрица. Элементы матрицы - целые числа, по модулю не превосходящие 1000. В последних двух строках записаны координаты элемента (индексация начинается с нуля), соседей которого нужно найти.

Формат вывода:
Напечатайте нужные числа в возрастающем порядке через пробел.

вот то что я попробовал но это не то, мне нужно чтобы он выводил координаты элемента

```
 a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
 for i in range(0,len(a)):
     if len(a) == 1:
         print(a[i])
     elif i < len(a)-1:
         print(a[i+1]+a[i-1],end=' ')
     else:
         print(a[0]+a[i-1],end=' ')
```

Не понимаю как нужно делать эту задачу, помогите плиз.

Comment: да извиняюсь, случайно отправил не редактированный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такая функция получилась, она возвращает список соседей с клеткой с индексом matrix[y][x], где y - номер строки, а x - номер столбца, то есть обычная индексация двумерного массива

```
def neighbors(matrix, y, x):
    h = []
    if x + 1 < len(matrix[0]):
        h.append(matrix[y][x + 1])
    if x - 1 >= 0:
        h.append(matrix[y][x - 1])
    if y + 1 < len(matrix):
        h.append(matrix[y + 1][x])
    if y - 1 >= 0:
        h.append(matrix[y - 1][x])
    return h


n = int(input())
m = int(input())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
y, x = int(input()), int(input())
print(*sorted(neighbors(matrix, y, x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

можно так сделать (чтобы не мучаться с проверками на границы):

```
n, m = map(int, input('размеры: ').split())
matrix = [list(map(int, input(f'строка {i}: ').split())) for i in range(n)]
y, x = map(int, input('позиция: ').split())

res = []
try: res.append(matrix[y][x+1])
except: pass
try: res.append(matrix[y][x-1])
except: pass
try: res.append(matrix[y+1][x])
except: pass
try: res.append(matrix[y-1][x])
except: pass

print(*sorted(res))
```